# [Ghidra]How to set global variable type?

Tags: ghidra, java

I have created a script in Java and I have a structure type as a string name which I want to set at given global variable which I have the Address of.

However I can't seem to find a way to do this - like I can get the symbol or something but this doesn't allow me to change the type.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a better fit for Stack Overflow because it doesn't contain any reverse engineering elements.

Comment: @dingo_kinznerhook: as [the OP pointed out here](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/424/245) this is indeed RE-related, given the Ghidra complex. Java alone would be for StackOverflow, of course, but in the context of Ghidra and asking about how to interface with that to accomplish something is clearly a fit.

Comment: well you can open .data section where u will find all initialized data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get the `DataType` that you want, for example `struct foo`:

`DataType dt = getDataTypes("foo")[0];`

Or if it's just a pointer you'll have to get the pointer of that type.

You said you already have the address, you'll need to make sure it's an `Address` if not already:

`Address addr = toAddr(0x12345678);`

Then create the data:

`Data data = createData(addr, dt);`

It may already have something there if that fails, you can clear out that memory (there is another API for this if you need more control, this is the simple case):

`clearListing(addr, addr.add(dt.getLength() - 1);`